# Using 3D transforms with iOS (iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation

I'm getting a compile time error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" when trying to use any 3D animation stuff like CATransform3DIdentity or CATransform3DMakeScale.

I'm using them like this:

```
imgV.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(512, 384, -100);
```

Any ideas?

pom

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem this morning.  I had to add the QuartzCore framework for this to work.